# Finding the flux of $\iint \vec F\hat n\;ds$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, physics, stochastic-analysis

I need to find the flux $\displaystyle\iint \vec F\hat n\;ds$ of the vector feild $\vec F=4x  \hat i-2y^2\hat j+z^2 \hat k$ throughe the surface $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=4,z=0,z=3\}$

**My attempt:**

(I'm not sure that I know what I'm doing)

curl $\vec F=\nabla\times F=\bigg(\frac{\partial(4x)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial (-y^2)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial (z^2)}{\partial z}\bigg)=\bigg(4-2y+2z\bigg)$

Now applying Stock's theorem

$$\iiint\bigg(4-2y+2z\bigg)dxdydz$$

> Is it correct so far?

Comment: Do you mean that the surface is closed, i.e the cylinder with the one base at z=0 and the other at z=3 ?

Comment: If so, then you do not need Stokes. This is just a surface integral of the second kind.

Comment: Is that a tensor $\vec F\,\hat n$ in the surface integral or is there intended to be an inner product $\hat n \cdot \vec F$ or perhaps a cross product $\hat n \times \vec F$?

Comment: Just FYI ... The Curl maps a vector into a vector.  Your result is a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div$\vec F=\bigg(\frac{\partial(4x)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial (-y^2)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial (z^2)}{\partial z}\bigg)=\bigg(4-2y+2z\bigg)$

$$\iint_{S}\vec F\cdot \hat n \;ds=\iint_{V}div\vec F \;dv=\iiint_{V}\bigg(4-2y+2z\bigg) \;dxdydz$$

$$x=\rho \cos \varphi,\; y=\rho \sin \varphi, \; z=z$$

$$0\leq z \leq3, \; 0\leq \rho \leq 2, \; 0\leq\varphi\leq 2 \pi$$

$$\iiint_{V}\bigg(4-4y+2z\bigg)dxdydz=\int_0^3dz\int_0^2d\rho\int_0^{2\pi}\rho(4-4\rho\sin\varphi+2z)d\varphi$$

$$=\int_0^3dz\int_0^22\pi\bigg(4\rho+2\rho z\bigg)d \rho=48\pi+36\pi=\boxed{\color{red}{84\pi}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Gauss Theorem (divergent theorem), since it deals with flux:

$$
\nabla F = 4-4y+2z
$$

$$
\int_{V} \nabla F dV = \int\int \vec{F}\vec{n}dS
$$

Your volume is define by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $0 \leq z \leq 3$.

Comment: You have a vector on the left-hand side and a tensor on the right-hand side.

Comment: I guess that the inner product $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}dS$ is implicit in his problem.

Comment: Is it?  Why does one assume that?  It could as easily be $\vec F \times \hat n$, could it not?

Comment: He needs to determine the flux... Stock's theorem does not evaluate fluxes, but potentials over closed loops.

Comment: Plus, in some text books, the dot product is assumed when the dot is omitted.

Comment: I don't assume a gender, but yes if one is talking about flux then one ought to write things correctly

Comment: What text book?

Comment: Some Electromagnetims books, for example... (William Hayt, etc...)

Comment: Hayt does not omit the dot.   I taught EM for 7 years, both undergraduate and graduate levels and I have never seen ambiguous notation of the sort discussed herein used by any author.

Comment: It may be because I used a translated edition. Although I also saw some articles that also omit the dot. Don't remember now, but as soon as I see one, I will post here for you...

Comment: If one omits the dot, then certainly $\int_S \hat n\,\vec F\,dS=\int_V \nabla\,\vec F\,dV$ could be interpreted as $\int_S \hat n\times \vec F\,dS=\int_V \nabla \times \vec F\,dV$ or the actual tensor form as it is written.